# glfwGetCursorPos returning int values

Tags: java, lwjgl, glfw

I want to implement an FPS-style mouse look in my lwjgl3 java application.
But when I use `glfwGetCursorPos` to get the cursor position.

But the problem is that `glfwGetCursorPos` is returning doubles but the decimal places are always zero.

Is there any workaround for that issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can't get more precise values, because the mouse position is always on one pixel.

If you want to get values between 0 and 1 you can dived mouseX and mouseY by the window width and window height.